# Different Static Resource for different layout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

For my working purpose, I need to **create a custom layout** in **Magento 2**.

But I want to **add specific CSS** resource in the head for only that layout.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing ***static files*** of a theme.
[Static view files](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html#theme-structure-pub)

let's say you have created your custom layout in :

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout

Create a template file in

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\web\template

from that template file you can put your custom html element and you can assign custom classes whatever you want and like.

> Check this sample (assuming you have your own registered custom module)

**First** create a **layout** under **frontend/layout** directory and name it as
**checkout_index_index.xml**
with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
<css src="css/custom.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename/onepage</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="note" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename/note</item>
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">note</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Then after that create your **html templates** which are *note and onepage(with html extension) under

> **Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\web\template**  directory

**note.html**

```
 <p style="notes">This is styled with a custom css</p>
```

**onepage.html**
put this code

```
<div class="opc-wrapper">
    <ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </ol>
</div>
```

Create your **custom css** under

> view/frontend/web/css/custom.css

add this code

```
.notes{
    color: blue !important;
    }
```

go to put the custom css to your **`custom layout`**

to be specific put it before

```
<body> tag
```

put it like this

```
<head>
    <css src="css/custom.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/>
</head>
```

then try to **`cache:flush`**  check the checkout page to check the changes
if flushing cache does not change anything try to run **`setup:upgrade`** then run **`static-content:deploy`** command

Comment: can you give the full code? This is very theoretical.

Comment: @Shuvankar Paul, I have updated my answer with the sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a layout as per your specific module controller. Let's assume your custom controller as http://thelegendarysite.com/modulefrontname/controllername/actionname

So here are the steps

1. Create a XML file with following contents at the location

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/modulefrontname_controllername_actionname.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
   <css src="NameSpace_ModuleName::css/custom.css"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

2. Add a custom.css file at the location

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css

3. Perform

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and

> php bin/magento cache:flush

from the document root of your site to see the changes and this would only be applied to the controller selected.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare that `css` in that custom `layout`.

Assuming that your custom layout is : `prince_stack_index.xml`

`prince` = your route, declared in `routes.xml`

`stack` = controller folder.

`index` = controller name.

So 1) : `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/prince_stack_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Modulename::css/mystyle.css" />
        <!-- or if you want to place the mystyle.css in your theme : -->
   <!-- <css src="Magento_Theme::css/mystyle.css" /> -->
    </head>
</page>
```

2) `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/css/mystyle.css`

```
Your css content goes here
```

or the **theme** case: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/mystyle.css`

3) Clean the **content** of `pub/static` without the `.htaccess` then, deploy the static content like this : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`